# Embedding Tableau dashboard on GitHub Pages

Tags: tableau-api, github-pages, embedding

Does anyone know of a good tutorial for embedding interactive Tableau dashboards on GitHub Pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this webpage
https://tableau.github.io/embedding-playbook/

you can basically embed using Javascript API

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://www.example.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.js"></script>
<div id="tableauViz"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function initializeViz() {
var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
var url = "http://public.tableau.com/views/WorldIndicators/GDPpercapita";
var options = {
 width: '600px',
 height: '600px',
 hideTabs: true,
 hideToolbar: true,
 };
viz = new tableau.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options);
}
```